# Get sum of looped numbers python

Tags: python

Not sure how to word the question, but I have got this lil script to go through a bunch of .csv's in a directory and count all the non-blank cells. Where printing the total is no issue.

I want to get the sum of these however but can't get some different options to work.

```
import pandas
import os
import numpy as np

homedir = (r"D:\\python\\XXX")

for filename in os.listdir(homedir):
    if filename.endswith(".csv"):
       #Reads csv file and converts it to pandas dataframe.
        fName = os.path.join(homedir + filename)
        df = pandas.read_csv(fName, na_values='', keep_default_na=False)
        # Gets length of dataframe and displays it.
        print(np.count_nonzero(df.values)+ 1)

        total = (np.count_nonzero(df.values)+ 1)
        b = sum(total)
        print (b)
```

***Have tried, to no avail***

```
    total = (np.count_nonzero(df.values)+ 1)
    b = sum(total)
    print (b)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it looks like you are currently printing the number of empty cells when printing `total` now, which is great. I will say that `np.count_nonzero` returns an integer here (which you add one to) then you are trying to compute the sum of an integer which wont end nicely (sum function wants an iterable like a list in python...).

Do you want the `sum` to be over all of the data sets (whereas the `total` is particular to one)? Then you could try something like:

```
import pandas
import os
import numpy as np

homedir = (r"D:\\python\\XXX")

total_list = [] # A structure to record the totals in.
for filename in os.listdir(homedir):
    if filename.endswith(".csv"):
       #Reads csv file and converts it to pandas dataframe.
        fName = os.path.join(homedir + filename)
        df = pandas.read_csv(fName, na_values='', keep_default_na=False)
        # Gets length of dataframe and displays it.
        print(np.count_nonzero(df.values)+ 1)

        total = (np.count_nonzero(df.values)+ 1)
        total_list.append(total)

print(sum(total_list))
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, that's a lot cleaner than the way I solved it just before. I had ended up counting the blanks and then taking that away from the non-blanks